# adding virtualhost url for mysql

Tags: mysql, debian, virtualhost

I have a local dev machine on a virtualbox that mirrors a live vps (deb squeeze amd64). I would like to set up a host name for mysql in the same way I have added hostnames via httpd.conf for normal web url. Can you advise what I need to change/add?

thx
Art

web-url blah.com (servered from v1.blah.com)

mysql  mydb.blah.com  **this is what I would like to add**

httpd.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@blah.com
ServerName v1.blah.com
ServerAlias v1.blah.com blah.tv
DocumentRoot /home/myuser/v1.blah.com
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin /home/myuser/cgi-bin
<Directory /home/myuser/v1.blah.com/>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
AccessFileName .htaccess
ErrorLog /home/myuser/blah_logs/v1.blah.com.in-error_log
CustomLog /home/myuser/blah_logs/v1.blah.com.in-access_log common 
</VirtualHost>
```